# https somehow get's re-writen into http and causes me error

Tags: http, https, apache2, proxypass

Simply put, I have a custom software that runs it's own webserver. I then found instructions on how to use apache as a proxy that will enable ssl for that site. (long story short, my custom software doesn't support ssl and it's not an option)

When I go to `https://myserver.com:8096/` (port is forwarded internally to 443), the server re-writes the url as `http://myserver.com:8096/abc/123/` which causes the connection to fail because it's expecting HTTPS.

Here is my default-ssl config, Hopefully I just have a mistake in there somewhere...

```
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/key-cert.pem

    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyVia On

    ProxyPass /webdav/ http://127.0.0.1:8069/webdav/
    <Location /webdav/ >
            ProxyPassReverse /webdav/
            <Limit OPTIONS PROPFIND GET REPORT MKACTIVITY PROPPATCH PUT MOVE COPY DELETE LOCK UNLOCK>
                    Order Deny,Allow
                    Allow from all
                    Satisfy Any
            </Limit>
    </Location>

    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8069/
    <location / >
            ProxyPassReverse /
    </location>

    RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https"

    # Fix IE problem (httpapache proxy dav error 408/409)
    SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

    ErrorDocument 400 'ERROR!'
    ErrorDocument 403 'ERROR!'
    ErrorDocument 404 'ERROR!'
    ErrorDocument 503 'ERROR!'
```

*the missing /VirtualHost is there, I just can't figure out how to get it to display on here...*

Anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up installing nginx and found that I had the same behavior.

This rules out Apache in my opinion and I consider this thread complete.
I will look on the other web server to see what else I can find.

cheers